# MVC if checkbox is checked return true to controller and if it isn't, return false

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

Currently I have a checkbox that looks like this

```
 Adjust inventory levels <input type="checkbox" name="invChkBox" id="invChkBox" value="true" />
```

And my post controller method has parameters that look like this

```
 public ActionResult EditItemInstance(int ID, string serialNumber, int ItemID, bool invChkBox)
```

but when the chkBox isn't checked it returns an error page. That has an error message saying

**null entry for parameter 'invChkBox' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean'**

How can I edit my code so that it returns false if the checkbox is not clicked?

Comment: Why not use the html helper to create the checkbox?  it creates a hidden input for the false value or use `bool invChkBox = false` in your method so it defaults to false if nothing is posted

Comment: @Pete Thank you!